Infinite redirection loop when using Microsoft.Owin.Security and OpenIdConnectAuthentication
I was using this library: https://github.com/dylanplecki/KeycloakOwinAuthentication/tree/master
and recently we wanted to upgrade to use Owin middleware in a legacy old app, in summary this is my code,
i noticed that sometimes it logs in correctly, and sometimes it's stuck in an infinite loop of redirection that stops once i force refresh the page in the browser, after that it login correctly.
`
            app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(persistentAuthType);

           
            app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
            {
                AuthenticationType = persistentAuthType,
                AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Active,
                CookieManager = new Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.SystemWebChunkingCookieManager(),
                CookieSecure = CookieSecureOption.Always,
                CookieHttpOnly = true
            });

            

            var authenticationOptions = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
            {
                ClientId = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ClientIdWeb"],
                CookieManager = new Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.SystemWebChunkingCookieManager(),
                ClientSecret = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ClientSecretWeb"],
                Authority = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["KeyCloakUrl"] + "/auth/realms/" + WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Realm"],
                Scope = OpenIdConnectScope.OpenIdProfile,
                AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Active,
                ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.Code,
                SignInAsAuthenticationType = persistentAuthType,
                ProtocolValidator = new OpenIdConnectProtocolValidator()
                {
                    RequireNonce = false,
                    RequireStateValidation = false
                },
                RedirectUri = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["KeyCloakRedirectURI"],
                RedeemCode = true,
                SaveTokens = true,
                UsePkce = false,
                TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidateIssuer = false,
                    RoleClaimType = ClaimTypes.Role,
                    NameClaimType = "preferred_username"
                }

            };

            app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
                authenticationOptions
            );

I am not so much familiar with the authentication flow and i tried many solutions but still the same issue.
when i try to add logs in OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications, it seems to get stuck at MessageReceived.
and also i noticed that during the loop the cookies are set and removed at each redirection.
I tried using SystemWebCookieManager, but the problem was not resolved, and it was not affected by the force-refresh.
